# if with regex - string matches either entire string OR entire string + another character?

Tags: regex, bash, macos, if-statement, command-line

Sorry if a question like this already has an answer, I wasn't really sure how to word this, so I'll try my best.

How can I make an if statement match an entire string, OR an entire string with an extra character?

---

Let's say the `$animals` variable has `,dog,cat,pig,bird,goat,` stored in it. I want to see if the user-defined variable `$your_pet` is either one of the comma-separated values OR if it is with an "s" at the end.

So maybe something that would work like:

```
your_pet=bird

if [[ "${your_pet}" == ,*"${animals}"*, || "${your_pet}"s == ,*"${animals}"*, ]]
then
....
```

**However**, I need to check if `$your_pet` ends in an "s" or not, and accept it if it does or doesn't. (The above code is untested but I am almost certain it would not work).

Here are all of the allowed values of `$your_pet`:

```
dog
dogs
cat
cats
pig
pigs
bird
birds
goat
goats
```

And here are some examples of what would **not** be allowed:

```
my dog
my dogs
 dog
hamster
hamsters
```

I feel like using regex in the if statement would do the trick but I don't know that much about regex to know what to use. (if regex is even needed in a situation like this)

Using bash 3.2.57(1)-release on OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan

Thanks

Comment: This might help: `[[ "$animals" =~ ,cats{0,1}, ]] && echo match`

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks, but I need to check if `$your_pet` (with or without an "s") matches anything in `$animals`

Comment: What about plurals that don’t just add an “s”, eg “platypus” and “platypuses”, “ox” and “oxen”. Your approach is based on an oversimplification of how plurals are formed. If I were implementing this, I would simply store both singular and plural forms of every animal in your collection. It makes for simple, understandable and reliable code.

Comment: @Bohemian This is just a simple example, in my actual use case this will never be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `s` (if present) and then compare if it matches

```
your_pet=bird

if [[ "$animals" =~ ",${your_pet%s}," ]]
then
   ...
```

however, take into account other plurals like *goose, geese*.

Comment: Works for me, thanks! And yes, in the actual application I plan on using this in differently spelt plurals won't be an issue

Comment: How does this compare to something like: `if [[ "$animals" == *",${your_pet%s},"* ]]`?